# How to report and quantify the random effect in a logistic model? glmmTMB

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmmtmb

I'm fitting a logistic regression model with mixed effects using the package glmmTMB. (Because the dataset is very large and lme4 produces out of memory errors).
And I need help to interpret and report the output.

```
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula:      OUTPUT ~ SEX + YEAR + OTHER +  (1|CITY/ID)
Data: mydata

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 890000  891000 -450000  889000    1000000 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID:CITY (Intercept) 10.0    3.1 
 CITY    (Intercept) 1.5    1.2
Number of obs: 1000009, groups:  ID:CITY, 200000; CITY, 20

Conditional model:
             Estimate Std.Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.79   0.28    2.9   0.005
SEX1       -0.21   0.017 -12   <2e-16
YEAR        0.48   0.0048 100   <2e-16 
OTHER       -0.70   0.005 -130   <2e-16
```

Output from sjPlot:

```
Random Effects
σ2  3.29
τ00 ID:CITY 10.0
τ00 CITY    1.5
ICC 0.78
```

How can I report the effect of CITY?
I think most people would calculate the Confidence Interval of the odds of the Intercept with the variance as

```
 { exp(Intercept-1.96*1.2) , exp(Intercept+1.96*1.2) }
```

but this doesn't take into account the standard error of the Intercept from the conditional model, 0.28. How should I combine them?
(I think this is the estimated deviation for the Intercept excluding the random effects).

Is it acceptable to disregard the Intercept value and just say...?
"The 95% Confidence Interval for the odds ratio for CITY is {exp(-1.96*1.2),exp(+1.96*1.2)}"

or

"The odds of OUTPUT is multiplied by a number between exp(-1.96*1.2) and exp(+1.96*1.2) due to the variability of CITY". I don't know how to include here the 95% argument.

I have also tried to calculate the residuals with residuals(model) but it produces an out of memory error.
Is there any way to do it approximately?

I just need to say what proportion of the total variance (or of the residuals) is explained by the variable CITY.

The σ2 value reported by sjPlot is the variance of the residuals.

What about the variance of ID:CITY (Intercept) 10.0? How should I report it? How can I split it in variance due to ID and variance of the interaction of ID and CITY?

Comment: Where does the 1.2 in your formulae come from ? `CITY` is a (categorical) grouping variable for which you are fitting random intercepts so it doesn't make sense to think of an odds ratio for it. As for the variance of the residuals, this is fixed  - it is the variance of the logistic distribution, $\pi^2/3$. As for reporting the variances for the random effects, the usual approach is just to calculate a variance partition coefficient for each "level"

Comment: OK, and how can I calculate  a variance partition coefficient for each level?
How can I calculate the proportion of variance of the odds explained by CITY and explained by ID?

Comment: When I say the odds ratio of the CITY I mean something like...   
The different CITIES produce a variability on the Intercept, modeled with a distribution with Std.Dev 1.2.
I could calculate how the odds change for each CITY, get the Confidence Interval of all those values and report the 95%IC. Isn't it?
These two values would be exp(-1.96*1.2) and exp(+1.96*1.2).
Being in the lower side of that IC would multiply the odds of the OUTPUT by exp(-1.96*1.2).

Comment: Where does 1.2 come from ? I see 1.5 in the output. So, you are proposing to extract the individual intercepts for each city and calculate an odds ratio for each one ? As for proportion of variance, the usual approach is the divide the variance at each level by the total variance of the random effects, so 1.5 / (3.29 + 10 + 1.5) = 0.1 for `CITY` and 10 / (3.29 + 10 + 1.5) = 0.68 for `ID`